# About independence and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Can anyone give me a little hint on a the following question? Many thanks!!

The question is: If we know that $x$ and $z$ are independent, and $y$ and $z$ are independent, is it true that 
$$z\cdot\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y)=\mathbb{E}(zx\,|\,y)?$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Try $x=y=a$ almost surely for some constant $a\neq 0$. Then choose $z$ such that the equality does not hold.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!